# Google Play Games notifications not visible

Tags: google-play-games

I've looked through all questions on SO about Google Play Games, but looks like I'm the only one having problems now.

Using new GPG with Games.Achievements.unlock(), the achievement notification isn't showing up. I can see that achievement is unlocked when checking in unlocked achievements list, but that badge - it just doesn't show up!

The app isn't published, but has all the achievements correctly set up in Play Store. other GPG features seem to work fine, but they usually do not show notification (like Leaderboards)

And another issue that might be actually related to this. The initial login popup, the one that allows to pick an account when you have several of them on the device - sometimes it ends up being behind the app screen. And when you quit the app it keeps sitting on the device screen until you close it by picking Cancel. Not sure, this might be a debug issue due to app being force-closed on every next installation, but still.

Any ideas? How Achievement badge can end up being invisible all the time?

Comment: I had a similar issue, where it would only show up occasionally. In my case it was because I forgot to implement the `onActivityResult` for `GameHelper` (I did not extend `BaseGameActivity`). I still had to call `gameHelper.onActivityResult()` from my activities' `onActivityResult`.

Comment: @AAverin, did you resolve this?  I've just come across this problem - the notification has always showed up until recently, when one time it didn't - the achievement does unlock though.  Again, my game isn't published.

Comment: @Zippy I don't really remember, unfortunately. This issue was more then 1 year ago, and I don't recall what I did to resolve it. My only hope is that google made some updates to GPG library that resolved this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to try changing the popup view, depending on which implementation you have used, this is the basegameutils method:

```
Games.setViewForPopups(getApiClient(), getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content));
```

Depending on your code, you may need to use a different view.

Comment: May god bless you till eternity. You and your next 7 generations stay blessed! That did the trick dude. I am so happy !

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the activity view in which you want the notifications to be seen : Games.setViewForPopups(getApiClient(), getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content));

The issue was that I was calling Games.Achievements.unlock(mGoogleApiClient, context.getResources().getString(R.string.achievement_pro)); from a helper class. The context that I passed was of MainActivity.class, however I actually intended to show the achievements being unlocked in my GameScreen.class and not the MainActivity.class since it would be in the background. GameScreen.class, in my case, is an activity that I invoke through an Intent from MainActivity.class. And I suppose, it is because of this that the context is not set properly for Games.Achievements and it could not show the pop ups in my current activity screen.

When I added that line of code in GameScreen.class, I assume that now Games class knew where it has to popup the alerts. My explanation might sound a bit fussy here but let me know if you have any issue.